# Does the Apple Watch need an iPhone to be on the latest iOS to pair?

Tags: apple-watch

My S0 sport won't pair with my iPhone 6s on a 11.1.x version of iOS. I can't actually update my iPhone at the moment but this is the only suggestion the engineers have given.

The Apple Watch page doesn't mention series 0 anymore but for series 1 mentions Apple Watch Series 1 require an iPhone 5s or later with iOS 11 or later so I guess if they're compatible my phone meets the requirements. All I hear is "update, update, update", I wish I could but it's not an option for me at the moment. I'm not sure how updating my phone would fix the problem either unless this is a bug. The support engineers tell me it isn't a bug, at least not a known one which prevents iOS 11.1.x pairing with S0 Apple Watch. Maybe there's something I don't understand.

My iPhone says

> watchOS 3.1.3 Your software is up-to-date.

My watch says

> Please continue set-up on iPhone.

I've rebooted, powered off & on, enabled airplane mode etc. etc. etc. more times than I can count but I can't get the watch to pair. Even doing a clean reinstall of iOS and multiple factory resets of the watch didn't help. It's a 42mm Aluminium Sport (S0?) pairing to an iPhone 6S.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I can't see anything in Apple's advertising that says it won't work on a version of iOS that is 11.x but isn't the latest :(

Comment: For what it's worth, watchOS 3.1.3 requires a minimum of iOS 10.2, so your iPhone easily surpasses this. Sounds like a bug! iOS 11.1 supports up to watchOS 4.1, but this isn't the latest watchOS version, perhaps that has something to do with it.

Comment: @grgarside my understanding was that watchOS versioning is dependent on the iOS version of the paired iPhone, ie. that the iPhone would install whichever version of watchOS that it itself is compatible with based on its current iOS version. I can't understand why it thinks 3.1.3 is up to date :(

Comment: I have this same problem. Now I can’t use my watch for anything. It’s driving me mad, not to mention all the time I’ve spent trying to get it to work. Has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had the identical issue today. Updating my phone to iOS 11.3 resolved the issue.

Comment: I'm unable to update to iOS 11.3 due to some software issues.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought you meant you couldn't update at that moment. What if you set it up on someone else's phone temporarily? Would that work?

Comment: I don't believe the watchOS version that comes with iOS 11.3 is compatible with iOS 11.1 . Unfortunately the upgrade process is one way so If I check and it isn't compatible then I cannot revert to an earlier version either.